# Enable ctrl-click to jump from EL to java module

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE (Galileo) with seam framework. I'm interested how to enable ctrl-click to jump from an EL to a java module (in jsf views)?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does recognize ctrl-click in JSF EL, such binding is defined in General>Editors>Text Editors>Hyperlinking. You will be able to use it only on variables defined in faces-config, so those are bound to the Classes before runtime. Am i wrong?